# How to help my cat de-stress / get back to normal after a stressful few days seemed to have left her on edge?

Tags: cats

I adopted a cat back in December and we have a great bond. She is a rescue and can be a little timid with new people sometimes but for the most part has done great with all my friends and others who have come over.

This weekend, my dad was staying at my house. And it was incredibly stressful both for her and myself. But even after he left, she's still a little tense and on edge. I want to do anything I can to help her get back to normal. Here are some further details:

My dad has never had a pet and therefore isn't a natural at it to begin with. So, the first thing he did after walking in was pick her up (which she doesn't really like to begin with. My friends pick her up but that was after they established trust). That put her on edge. And then he kept just sticking his hand in front of her face, as well as calling her name again and again while she was nearby, as if that was the way to bond. And he wasn't open to suggestions about it. She calmed down a little bit and joined me on the couch-- to sit in my lap like normal--while watching a movie. She did eventually cross over and sit in my dad's lap (like she would with my friends) but then he reached right above her head and whole body, basically his arm on top of her, to grab a beer. And was literally putting it right in front of her face, so she got scared and hopped off. I tried to explain that was uncomfortable for her but he told me I was overreacting. So, it didn't start off well.

after, there were just a lot of continual little stresses and changes over the course of the two days that further stressded her--- like loud noises early in the morning upstairs from him moving furniture around at like 5AM, constant moving around in the early hours upstairs when it is normally pitch quiet, using a loud drill right next to her and the loud vacuum (Several times), leaving the front & backyard doors open for 15 minutes in the early morning hours to "air out" the house, moving her food and water bowls, basically taking over the whole dining room and living room area where she would normally be free to hang out, etc. I tried to voice my concern over in-service things they came along but it was ignored.

Also, there are a couple things that she's a little afraid of, like the loud vacuum or opening a garbage bag right in front of her / over her. So I usually try to use those things when she's downstairs or in the other room or something. He didn't respect that at all. He would continually use it right next to her--causing her to get more scared.

She, understandably, also doesn't like the door to the basement to be closed entirely when she is down there because she feels trapped with no way out. And I always have it open anyways--even before I adopted her. But my dad kept closing it and I told him to please leave it at least a little open for her...she she can exit. But he didn't. And Every time, she would get scared and try to open it with her paws. I would immediately come up and open it for her. But then he kept closing it several more times right after.
He did not respect my concern at all and told me "My cat had to learn that "she doesn't rule the world"".

So, overall, it was just a lot of little stressful things for her over the course of the two days and I could see it bothering her.

When he picked her up the second time, it was also a weird position too and so she was trying to get down and started making vocalizations which she rarely does.

he is gone now, but I can tell she's still a little on edge and not quite back to her normal self. Like yesterday, she came up onto the couch to sit in my lap.  I moved my arm above my head, which I do often when I'm relaxing laying down, but even that scared her out and jumped off.

Obviously, I am not going to allow this to happen again--especially knowing the full scope of it now. But, I am worried for her. Is there anything I can do to help her de-stress from this? Will this cause her to be permanently on edge? I don't want her close relationship with me to change, or how cuddly and social she normally is with my friends who are respectful of her. Please let me know any suggestions!! Thanks!

Comment: I understand your situation and feel with you. It is hard for children AND parents to learn how to respect the children is a full grown adult now and has it's own way of live and to express this also in a polite manner. Even now (nearly 20 years my own life) if my mum is visiting, there are points she want to teach me. Not intenionally, but because she did it "her whole life" ^^ I need to remind her polite and asure her that it is not fading love to have my own rules at MY home. Same as I accept her rules at HER home :)

Comment: Does your cat have her own safe space? If not I recommend it as all cats need this to relax and destress. This is usually a small, quiet, covered, comfortable area which (preferably) only she has access to. You find she spends a lot of time there, to relax, sleep, groom herself, or whatever. We all need our own space and this includes animals. It sounds as though she may be using the basement for this purpose at the moment. Other than that, I recommend giving her treats and attention and playing with her. Cats like to play hunt :).

I hope things get better soon.